# Problem integraing Wiris math type and chem type with django using tiny mce editor

Tags: django, tinymce, integration, mathtype, wiris

I am new to Django. I want to integrate `wiris math type` plugin in tinymce into the Django template. Same thing works in `Laravel framework` but in `django` it is giving problem.

[image: error messages]

It is giving Failed to initialize plugin: tiny_mce_wiris

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add:

```
external_plugins: { tiny_mce_wiris: 'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/tiny_mce/plugin.js' },
```

below the selector and:

```
    | tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor | tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry |
```

to the toolbar in the script.